# What permissions besides AssumeRole are needed to be able to switch role to another account in AWS console?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a:

- a IAM role in AccountB `myrole` with a trust relationship to AccountA
- the role in AccountB has a policy associated to [only allow `eu-north-1`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_aws_deny-requested-region.html).
- an IAM user in AccountA with a policy to allow `AssumeRole` to role `myrole` in Account B

This *works for my test user* where only this policy that allows `sts:AssumeRole` is attached.

But I have a user in AccountA with a [`DenyAllOutsideEU` policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_aws_deny-requested-region.html) where the switch role operation in the aws console gives me a "*Invalid information in one or more fields. Check you information or contact your administrator*".

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "DenyAllOutsideEU",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "NotAction": [
                "cloudfront:*",
                "iam:*",
                "route53:*",
                "support:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "aws:RequestedRegion": [
                        "eu-west-1"
                    ]}}}]}
```

But when I do `aws sts assume-role  --role-arn arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxx:role/myrole --role-session-name yyyy` for that user in AccountA it successfully assumes the role. **So I know the `sts:AssumeRole` is not being denied.**

I know is this `DenyAllOutsideEU` policy that is causing it because if I add `sts:*` to the list of `NotAction` in the `DenyAllOutsideEu` policy in AccountA it **will start working**.

So what exactly happens after `sts:AssumeRole`, and what other permission is needed that is denied. I know I can just fixit by adding `sts:*` to the `DenyAllOutsideEU` but I want to understand exactly what is going on. I was expecting that after the successful `sts:AssumeRole` the AWS console would not do further request to AccountA so none of the permissions of user in AccountA would matter, but it's obviously not the case.

**Is AWS Console doing some other STS request user in AccountA towards another region after the `sts:AssumeRole`?**

Comment: Sorry, skipped right over it being a `NotAction`; deleted my answer. Only other thought is that this user is using a federated login to get to the console? There aren't a lot of STS calls to suspect. FWIW, I looked at our CloudTrail logs, and only see `AssumeRole`; that may not mean much, because CloudTrail doesn't capture everything.